# Isomorphism problem involving the dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that $ D_{2n} / \langle r^k\rangle \cong D_{2k}$ where $k|n$

Note: $< r^k > $ is normal in $ D_{2n}$

Im trying to see if my proof is valid.

Proof:

$ \frac{|D{2n}|}{|\langle r^k\rangle|} = \frac{2n}{\frac{n}{k,n}} = 2k $

and $|D_{2k}|= 2k$

Both $ D_{2n} / \langle r^k\rangle$ and $D_{2k}$ are subgroups of $D_{2n}$. However, they maybe of the same size but containg different elements of $ D_{2n}$

Let $D_{2k}$ act on $ D_{2n} / \langle r^k\rangle$ by left multiplication affording a Homomorphism  $\phi$

By the First Isomorphism Theorem the $\ker \phi$ must be 1 and we're done.

Comment: You must mean to assume $k \mid n$. I don't know what you're talking about with a homomorphism $\phi$ and $D_{2n}/\langle r^k\rangle$ being a subgroup of $D_{2n}$. If you can use a presentation for $D_{2n}$ and/or $D_{2k}$, it's straightforward--the quotient satisfies the presentation relations and is of the appropriate size. Alternatively an explicit isomorphism should be easy to come up with and prove directly.

Comment: Yea, $k|n$. Basically I've gotten it down to where $D_{2n}/<r^k>$ and $D_{2k}$ both are of size $2k$ and are subgroups of D2n. I'm not sure how to establish that they are the same subgroup. They can have different elements of $D_{2n}$. Since both are of size $2k$ this is why I thought of defining map ϕ to use the first isomorphism theorem to finish the proof. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: @Scripture A subgroup is in particular a subset. $D_{2n}/\langle r^k\rangle$ is not a sub_set_ of $D_{2n}$, so it cannot be a sub_group_ of $D_{2n}$. Since $\langle r^k \rangle$ is normal in $D_{2n}$, the quotient is indeed a group. It's just not a subgroup of $D_{2n}$. You should probably see your instructor, if you have one. They could clear this up quickly. I still have no idea what you mean by $\phi$; it certainly can't be the natural projection map from the first isomorphism theorem, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid because $ D_{2n} / \langle r^k\rangle$ is a quotient and not a subgroup.

Comment: But <r^k> is normal in $D_{2n}$